# HTML5 audio player disappears after filtering with jQuery quicksand

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio, quicksand

I am working on my website, using jQuery quicksand for sorting and filtering my portfolio. Within this portfiolio I use a HTML5 audio player with flash fallback. The first click on one of my categories is working fine so far but further filtereing leads to the HTML5 audio player being hidden from display. I thought that initialising the player after filtering might be the solution to this problem but that leads to strange track counts within the player. I've also tryed setting "display" of the player to "block" after filtering (instead of initialising it again) but it still won't show up. I can't think of anything else to solve this and would really appreciate any help in this matter.

Here you can see what exactly is happening: http://www.tina-pepper.com/00/#portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicksand removes the elements from the DOM and then sticks them back in. You'll need to use the `enhancement` parameter as seen in the [docs](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html#integration).

This may not take care of everything but it will take care of the strange counts.

```
// Reset the html in the numbers div to the initial state
$('.cj-music-numbers').html('/');
$.fn.cjMusicPlayer();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the enhancement parameters. I think my problem is that I don't know how to use it in conjunction with the audio player. I only know how to instantiate the player - if I do that with the enhancement parameter it makes things even worse (even more wrong track counts). I don't think this player has something like "refresh" (as cufon does).

Comment: What audio player are you using? I can take a look and see if there's anything you can do.

Comment: It's a player I bought on codecanyon. You can take a look at the script here:
http://www.tina-pepper.com/00/js/cj-music-player.js

Comment: I've updated my answer with something that will definitely take care of the track count issue. If there are other issues, let me know and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Kalley, thanks so much, that solved all the problems I had left. It takes care of the wrong numbers and it also sovles the problem with the disappearing player. You just made my day! :)